# What is the number of transition amplitudes needed to describe an $n$-qubit state?

Tags: qiskit, textbook-and-exercises

In [describing quantum computers](https://learn.qiskit.org/course/introduction/describing-quantum-computers) page in the fourth quick quiz it asks "An n-qubit state vector can contain up to $2^n$
amplitudes. What’s the largest number of transition amplitudes we’d need to represent any quantum operation on n qubits?"

My question is why is $4^n$ is wrong and $(2^n)^2$ is right, when $4^n = (2^n)^2$? Or is my math just wrong?  I tried $n=1,...,5$.  Isn't $(2^n)^2 = 2^{n\cdot 2} = 2^{2n} = (2^2)^n = 4^n$?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, both these answers should work.

My guess is, the quiz author was looking for alternative answers that looked similar to the correct one but were incorrect, and accidentally got a second correct one instead. If there is a way to provide feedback on that page, you can try letting the authors know - I know I'm always happy when someone catches a bug that I didn't!

Comment: I didn't see a way to provide feedback.  I was directed to this forum so I hope the author reads this.

Comment: @Tony please create an issue on Github page of the Qiskit Texbook: https://github.com/qiskit-community/qiskit-textbook/issues